# SQL Server, TSQL regex_exp to extract date which can have variable length

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

maybe someone has similar problem and can help or advice something, how resolve this in SQL Server, language: TSQL

I have some string in variable:

```
declare @importedFileName varchar(max)='C:\FileSystem\Import\2022\4\12\Document.Import.NewCustomer.j4898u9sdfsdf4345jh3b4h.docx'
```

I need extract only this piece:

```
2022\4\12
```

which can have different number of signs, for example:

```
2022\12\12 - length = 10
2022\1\1   - length = 8
2022\4\12  - length = 9
```

I did it, like that:

```
declare @extractDate varchar(max) = substring(@importedFileName,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%[0-9]%[0-9]%',@importedFileName),10)
declare @extract int = len(@extractDate)- PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',reverse(@extractDate))+2
declare @fileName varchar(max) =replace(substring(@extractDate,0,@extract),'\','_')
select @fileName
```

it works, but it looks, very unprofessional, even terrible

I wanted one regex_exp, something like:   %[0-9]%[0-9]%[0-9]  - but it doesn't work properly

Any suggestions?

Comment: SQL Server has no regular expressions. SSMS is just a client tool, it doesn't change how SQL Server works. SQL, the language, isn't good at text manipulation. It's a query language, not a general purpose language

Comment: SQL Server does not support Regex, only basic pattern matching. As such you would need 4 patterns (`yyyy\m\d`,`yyyy\m\dd`.`yyyy\mm\d`,`yyyy\mm\dd`) to check against, due to the choice to not use zero padded dates

Comment: Why are you trying to parse the string in SQL anyway? It's a *lot* easier to use another language to parse strings before you import them into the database. If you absolutely must, you can use SQL Server's Python support to execute a regular expression against a query's results with `sp_execute_external_script`. Check [Quickstart: Run simple Python scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/tutorials/quickstart-python-create-script?view=sql-server-ver15). Python is supported in all SQL Server versions in mainstream support, ie 2017 and later

Comment: Is your example string representative of your data generally? Ie you want to *extract* the data after the 3rd "\"  up to the 6th "\", would that be correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it.

```
DECLARE @importedFile VARCHAR(MAX) =
  'C:\FileSystem\Import\2022\04\04\Document.Import.NewCustomer.j4898u9sdfsdf4345jh3b4h.docx';

SELECT      TheDate = SUBSTRING(FrontOf.String,1,LEN(FrontOf.String)-Endof.String)
FROM        (VALUES(PATINDEX('%2[0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@importedFile)))  AS dt(Yr)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@importedFile,dt.Yr,10)))             AS FrontOf(String)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',REVERSE(FrontOf.String))-1)) AS Endof(String);
```

With a table:

```
DECLARE @imports TABLE(importFile VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @imports VALUES
('C:\FileSystem\Import\2022\04\04\Document.Import.NewCustomer.j4898u9sdfsdf4345jh3b4h.docx'),
('C:\FileSystem\Import\2022\6\14\??Document.Import.NewCustomer.5tttyadf4345jh3basff.docx'),
('C:\FileSystem\Import\2022\7\7\...Document.Import.NewCustomer.t09afgsv05jh3basff.docx');

SELECT
  Original  = i.importFile,
  NewString = f.TheDate
FROM  @imports AS i
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT      TheDate = SUBSTRING(FrontOf.String,1,LEN(FrontOf.String)-Endof.String)
  FROM        (VALUES(PATINDEX('%2[0-9][0-9][0-9]%',i.importFile)))  AS dt(Yr)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(i.importFile,dt.Yr,10)))             AS FrontOf(String)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',REVERSE(FrontOf.String))-1)) AS Endof(String)
) AS f;
```

**Results:**

```
Original                                                                        NewString
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
C:\FileSystem\Import\2022\04\04\Document.Import.NewCustomer.j4898u9sdf3b4h.docx 2022\04\04
C:\FileSystem\Import\2022\6\14\??Document.Import.NewCustomer.5tttyadf4ff.docx   2022\6\14
C:\FileSystem\Import\2022\7\7\...Document.Import.NewCustomer.t09afgsv0.docx     2022\7\7
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you effectively only have four patterns to check (assuming no years prior to 1000 or after 9999...), `PATINDEX` can do it:

```
DECLARE @importDate DATE;
SELECT @importDate = CONVERT(DATE, 
    MAX(
        REPLACE(
            SUBSTRING(@importedFileName, NULLIF(PATINDEX(p, @importedFileName), 0) + 1, l), 
            '\', '/'
        )
    ), 111
)
FROM (VALUES 
   ('%\[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\[0-9][0-9]\[0-9][0-9]\%', 10),
   ('%\[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\[0-9][0-9]\[0-9]\%', 9),
   ('%\[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\[0-9]\[0-9][0-9]\%', 9),
   ('%\[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\[0-9]\[0-9]\%', 8)
) _(p, l);

SELECT @importDate;
```

Of course this still doesn't look very nice, which is why you don't do string manipulation in T-SQL if you can avoid it. (Converting to a `DATE` wasn't asked for, but it's useful to show, and it's easy to remove if you don't need it.)